# Rails, Rspec, Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find link or button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I have an rspec test in rails that keeps failing, it says:

```
Failure/Error: click_on "New Part"

Capybara::ElementNotFound:
Unable to find link or button "New Part"
```

Here is my spec file:

```
    require "spec_helper"
describe "Adding and Registering a part" do

  it "shows a part not in a class" do
    company1 = Company.create(company_attributes)
    product1 = Product.create(product_1_attributes)
    product1.company = company1
    product1.save
    part1 = Part.new(part1_attributes)

    visit parts_path
    click_on "New Part"
    fill_in('part_part_number', :with => part1.part_number)
    fill_in('part_name', :with => part1.name)
    fill_in('part_description', :with => part1.description)
    fill_in('part_manufacturer', :with => part1.manufacturer)
    click_on "Create Part"
    visit parts_path
    expect(page).to have_text(part1.part_number)
    expect(page).to have_text(part1.name)
    expect(page).to have_text(part1.description)
    expect(page).to have_text(part1.manufacturer)
  end

  it "shows a part in a class after Register" do
    company1 = Company.create(company_attributes)
    product1 = Product.create(product_1_attributes)
    product1.company = company1
    product1.save
    part1 = Part.new(part1_attributes)

    visit parts_path
    click_on "New Part"
    fill_in('part_part_number', :with => part1.part_number)
    fill_in('part_name', :with => part1.name)
    fill_in('part_description', :with => part1.description)
    fill_in('part_manufacturer', :with => part1.manufacturer)
    click_on "Create Part"

    visit products_path
    click_on "Show"
    click_on "Register Parts"
    click_on "Register"
    expect(page).to have_text("Parts Registered")
    expect(page).to have_text(part1.name)
  end
end
```

and here is the link that cannot be found by capybara:

```
<%= link_to 'New Part', new_part_path %>
```

The spelling of "New Part" is exactly the same (I copy and pasted it from the link to the rspec test just to be safe), I have a similar rspec test that is on another page and works.

Comment: can you access parts_path directly on your server ? (for example without any authorization etc ?) . What steps you have in the passing tests before visitis parts_path ?

Comment: Your "New Part" link isn't being rendered on your page. Use `save_and_open_page` within your spec to preview the page in your browser and debug.

Comment: Did not think about it, duh, thank you Shani, the page does require authorization before accessing it!  Also thanks for the tip Anthony!

Comment: As an extra tip -- once you move to JS capable drivers - click_on will be asynchronous, which means calling `click_on` immediately followed by 'visit' will often lead to really flaky tests - instead you should get used to doing  `click_on 'Something'` then `expect(page).to have_content('something that indicates the click has completed')` then `visit`