# Rspec testing, Capybara unable to find link or button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

This the part of my requests test that fails:

```
scenario 'Admin destroys a job posting + gets notified' do
  parent = create(:parent)  
  create(:assignment, user_id: @user.id, role_id: 1)
  demand = create(:demand, shift_id: 4)
  sign_in(@user)
  visit demands_path

  click_on 'Destroy'
  expect(page).to have_content('successfully')
end
```

This is the error:

```
 Failure/Error: click_on 'Destroy'

 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   Unable to find link or button "Destroy"
```

And here is the corresponding index view, including a "Destroy" link in the app:

[image]

Any idea why this test fails??

Comment: Please change the title of the question. It's not accurate. RSpec has nothing to do with finding an element on the page. It's the responsibility of the driver that you're using with Capybara. In order to debug this issue, you can use `binding.pry` or `byebug` and you need to make sure that there is a link with the text "Destroy" in your page and that the link is visible. This question might be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36975204/rails-rspec-capybaraelementnotfound-unable-to-find-link-or-button

Comment: are you using javascript? if so, does the capybara driver supports javascript? try using byebug before click_on destroy

Comment: How is `sign_in` defined, and the image doesn't show 'Destroy'

Comment: @ThomasWalpole whoops, wrong screenshot! gonna correct that right away

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Odds are the data you assume is on the page actually isn't.  This could be for a number of reasons.

1. Your page requires JS and you're not using a JS capable driver - see https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#drivers
2. Your `sign_in` method is defined to fill in user/pass and then click a button, but doesn't have an expectation for content that confirms the user has completed login at the end.  This can lead to the following visit occurring before login has completed and therefore not actually logging in.  Verify that by inspecting the result of `page.html` or calling `page.save_and_open_screenshot` before the click.
3. Your 'Destroy' "button" is neither an actual <a> element or <button> element.  Fix that by either using semantic markup or swapping to `find(...).click`
4. You are using a JS capable driver but your records aren't actually visible to the app - this would affect all your tests though so I assume it's probably not this.  If this was the case the login would fail  and you'd probably need to install database_cleaner and configure for use with RSpec & Capybara - https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner#rspec-with-capybara-example